# Почему ошибка Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>, line 3, pos 15

Tags: python, list

```
n = ' '.join(input().split(','))
n = ' ; '.join(n.split(';')).split()
total = ['\n' n[i] for i in range(len(n)) if n[i] == ';' elif int(n[i]) > 
    1000000000]
print(','.join(total))
```

я плохо составляю списочные выражения, но по условию надо, не суть, код жалуется на эту ошибку. Помогите как нормально перестроить данное выражение. Как использовать if и elif внутри списочного выражения?

По идеи, работает это как то так

```
if n[i] == ';':
    total.append('\n')
elif int(n[i]) > 1000000000:
     total.append(n[i])
```

Comment: иф-елиф нормально, проблема с `'\n' n[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вы не совсем верно подошли к решению задачи.

Исходя из кода, который вы предоставили можно предположить следующее -
на вход программе подается строка, значения в которой разделены с помощью `;`:

```
1;2;3,4;5;6
```

если значение превышает пороговое, то необходимо добавить значение в результирующий набор.

Поскольку вам и дальше нужно работать со значениями как со списком, проще не преобразовывать его в строку, а оставить списком

```
n = input().split(',')
```

далее, ваши значения внутри списка разделены с помощью другого разделителя `;`

```
total = [ '\n'.join(v for v in values.split(';') if int(v) > 1_000_000_000)
          for values in n]
```

ну и далее вы выводите значения также разделяя их запятыми:

```
print(','.join(total))
```

Если честно, то не совсем понятен формат, в котором должны быть представлены выходные данные.